# How can I renew a New York driver license from outside the US?

Tags: us-citizens, driving-license, online-resources

Can I renew my New York driving license online. I am visiting the UK for a year right now, and it expires in 5 months. I do have my residence in New York. I have my US passport with me and my New York drivers license, but won't be able to return to the US for another 6 months, until after it expires.

Comment: I need help renewing my licence and staying abroad for a while

Comment: @LuisColonJr This is not a comment on the previous question, but instead appears to be a question in itself. Please do not post questions in comments. If you have new question, ask it using the the "Ask Question" button found at the upper right on most every page,

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica, It's not clear that the previous comment isn't prompting for the same issue. And 'me too' questions are appropriate for comments, especially as that prevent duplicates from cropping. I just wonder if Luis Colon Jr actually read the answer posted to this question. It might be the solution to their problem as well.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might be able to renew it, even while you're out of the country.

Please refer to the [New York DMV website on renewing your license](https://dmv.ny.gov/driver-license/renew-license).

If you try to renew online, your new driver's license will not be forwarded to your foreign address. Instead you should renew by mail. That will also allow you to send in a vision test report that you can have done locally. Here's what they say:

> Overseas (out of the country, abroad)
>
> When overseas we recommend that you renew your driver license through
>   the mail.
>
> Send us:
>
> - the renewal notice we mailed you (MV-2) or if you don't have it, a completed Application for Permit, Driver License, or Non-driver ID
>     (MV-44)
> - a Vision Test Report (MV-619) completed by an eye care professional
> - a check or money order payable to ‘Commissioner of Motor Vehicles’
>
> We also recommend that you send us a pre-addressed priority mail
>   return envelope with your application (this will help ensure that we
>   send your license to the correct address).